# As a man, is it appropriate/inoffesnive to wear burqa for protection against COVID-19?

Tags: non-muslim, hijab, health

First off, I am not a Muslim, nor do I wish to cause offense to any Muslims.

Recently with all the obligation of wearing a facemask at all times I have been wondering, why not make it even more protective?  Wearing a full head-covering would be better it seems.  And my genius Muslim brothers and sisters have invented attire that not only serves this purpose, but is also rather stylish as well.

I am sensitive however to this being a garment of religious significance, and that it may be considered offensive or cultural appropriation, for a nonbeliever to use it for a purpose it is not intended.  Maybe even moreso, since I am a man.

Yet the idea of being able to walk around with my head and face fully covered is still appealing, as long as it is not upsetting.

Comment: In islam, men don't wear women like clothes and vice versa.

Comment: The Afghani-style burqa would be little use against the coronavirus [it's sometimes confused with the niqab, which would probably be a bit better].  Generally Muslim face coverings are loose at the bottom to allow women to breathe---they're not designed to stop viruses.

Answer (score 2):

In Islam, it is not allowed to behave or wear dresses like the opposite gender. The same goes for burqa for men. It is completely haram.

Even if I take COVID-19 into consideration, burqa isn't halal for men. It will be halal only if the burqa could save him from the virus. Because it doesn't have a filter rate of 100%.

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed for Muslim Men and Muslim Women to adopt attires that make them similar to the opposite gender, and whomever commits this sin has been cursed by the Prophet Peace Be Upon Him himself.

*However, if you are above the islamophobic propaganda and stereotypes,* and want to adopt a burqa like attire to cover the whole body, I suggest looking into the Saudi attire of a THAWB with a cloth covering the head. Add a mask to that and you have your whole body covered.

Hope that helps.